# Use of "on" vs "in" when referring to one's place of employment

Tags: word-choice

When should I write *in* or *at* while writing on a work place?

For example, should I write

> Meet John, he is a data engineer in a gaming company.

or

> Meet John, he is a data engineer at a gaming company.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question asks about *on vs in*, but your examples are *at vs in*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*At* would be the preferred preposition in the case you provided, but it somewhat depends on the context.

Use *at* and *for* when describing the company.

> I work *at* a gaming company.
>
> I work *for* a gaming company.

Use *on* when describing the projects you do.

> I work *on* video-games.

Use *in* when describing your field.

> I work *in* video-game development.